# Which processors support __builtin_clz?

Tags: c++, clang, built-in

Is there a reference somewhere that tells me which processors support 'clz' natively? Can I assume almost all desktops, servers, and mobile phones will support it?

I tried using `__builtin_ffs` instead since it's lack of undefined behavior at 0 saved me instructions in performance critical code but in benchmarks it was 10x slower than `__builtin_clz`, which makes it think it isn't hardware supported, even though `__has_builtin(__builtin_ffs)` is returning true. Need to run on any processor efficiently.

How can I be sure that clz won't have the same issue on some hardware?

Comment: If there is no native CPU instruction that maps to `__builtin_clz` what would you replace it with (and why do you think it'd be better than something compiler-generated)? Also, what do you mean by "it's lack of undefined behavior at 0 saved me instructions" (at the same time claiming 10x slower benchmarks)?

Comment: Any time you're talking about explicit builtin functions like this, you can't really make guarantees on speed on all hardware. You're going to be stuck with writing separate implementations by hardware, choosing which to use based on preprocessor checks, ideally with a pure C/C++ fallback for systems without hardware support, e.g. [one of the Bit Twiddling Hacks solutions for integer log base 2](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog).

Comment: @Dan M. What I mean is that within the critical locking part of code that multiple threads are running I don't need to check if the number being passed into __builtin_ffs is 0, like I do with __builtin_clz.  __builtin_clz according to llvm and gcc documentation has undefined behavior for 0.   I'd replace it with a fallback based on queues and a couple pointer swaps.

Comment: @hughmanwho compiler generally knows the behaviour of the target instructions it's compiling too and would eliminate the checks, if it matches the underlying HW behaviour, see: https://godbolt.org/z/o6h85b
It's not stupid (although it's not always smart enough either). Don't try to trick the compiler. Using `__builtin_ffs` to try to "elide" checks just means that the compiler would have to generate them themselves (to avoid UB in HW like on x86). Be straight-forward about your intentions and you'll get a reasonably optimized code for most mainstream targets which you can always fine-tune l8r.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yup, and it's true about guarantees on speed, though I was hoping some spec sheets from intel/amd could tell me if it supports it using a single instruction. I'm assuming my hardware does not do this for ffs, but idk. Should be as simple as if(num != 0) return (clz(num) + 1)

Comment: @hughmanwho what spec-sheets do you want? There is no guarantee about builtins mapping to some specific instruction. They are an abstraction for writing more portable code. There is only an expectation that the compiler would generate the most appropriate code implementing it for the target. Sometimes it's a single instruction, sometimes it's that + branch and other times it can be some li call or something else entirely.

Comment: If your compiler supports C++20 I'd highly suggest using the standard [`std::countl_zero`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countl_zero) method instead. It has the same behavior but is portable and may use the built ins underneath

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use BSR/BSF, perhaps via some inline assembly, because is supported on virtually any x86 processor.

https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bsr
https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bsf

And yes, you will need to deal with undefined behavior for zero input.

Comment: Good to know, if x86 is good about supporting BSR and ARM is good at their equivalent CLZ, probably for the moment this is good enough and i can hold off on implementing a fallback for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

> Which processors support __builtin_clz?

The `__builtin_clz` is a builtin function supported by your compiler. None processors support a `__builtin_clz` - your *compiler* supports that builtin. Gcc supports many architectures - I believe gcc will be able to compile code with `__builtin_clz` for any of them.

> Is there a reference somewhere that tells me which processors support 'clz' natively?

I believe a short google search should have resulted in [the nice wikipedia table Find_first_set#Hardware_support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Hardware_support).

> Can I assume almost all desktops, servers, and mobile phones will support it?

No idea. I would recommend not to - assuming something about environment leads to writing non-portable code.

> How can I be sure that clz won't have the same issue on some hardware?

A short algorithm that may help you:

- Write a short program that uses that compiler specific builtin.
- Compile the code for "some hardware".
- Inspect the generated by the compiler assembly code.
- If the generated assembly code is to your liking,

  - that means that you will not have the same issues,
  - otherwise you may have same issues.

I recommend to just write specific program paths that are specific to the hardware you care about, falling back to some generic portable solution on any other hardware you are not interested to handle. The hardware and compiler specific solutions would most probably use `__asm__` and `__builtin_*` functions.

Comment: I did do a little bit of searching, missed that one though. Looks great. And good idea about compiling it for specific hardware and looking at the assembly. Wonderful answer, thanks.